# Register multiple instances on IHostesService providing different IConfiguration to each instance

Tags: .net-core

I want to instance multiple agents, instances of the same long running task, injecting a specific configuration (a different `settings.json` or, *better*, a IConfigurationSection of the same main `appsettings`).

So I'm defining the Host in this way:

```
   services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, AgentService>(); // how to pass specific config??
   services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, AgentService>();
```

And implementing the IHostedService:

```
public class AgentService : BackgroundService
    {
        private IConfiguration configuration;
        private Logger log;
        public AgentService(
            IConfiguration Configuration
        )
        {
            this.configuration = Configuration;
            // this configuration should be specific and different for every AgentService instance!
            this.log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        }
        protected override async Task<int> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            try
            {
                log.Info("AgentService instance running...");
                log.Info($"{configuration.GetSection("CheckStatusTimer").Value}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error(e, $"Error executing worker: {e.Message}");
                return e.HResult; 
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `AddSingleton` isn't the same as `AddHostedService`. It won't register the service to start so `ExecuteAsync` won't be called unless you explicitly call it. `IConfiguration` provides access to all configuration settings. If you want different hosted services to read different settings, you can read from different *sections*.

Comment: You can use the [service factory version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionhostedserviceextensions.addhostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicecollectionhostedserviceextensions-addhostedservice-1(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-func((system-iserviceprovider-0)))) of `AddHostedService` to create services that read from different sections, passing the section name as a constructor param.

Comment: My idea is to use the very same service (same behavior) with slightly different running parameters; I'd love to define those parameters in an array of objects in appsettings.json. Imagine you must do some work on many targets, in parallel, and the targets differs only for their addesses, but the work to be done on them is the same.

Comment: Configuration settings come from multiple sources, not just `appsettings.json`. In fact, there's nothing special about that file. You could add as many JSON or XML or INI files as you want. Use `services.AddHostedService(svc=>new AgentService(configuration,"BananaSection"));` to register a hosted service with extra parameters. IConfiguration itself is registered as a DI service so you can call `svc.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>()` in the factory if there's no other `configuration` in the startup cod.

Comment: Thanks @Kanavos! You put me on the way... If you wish, you can answer, so I can upvote and mark answered.